# Confidence Interval and margin of error

Tags: statistics

I had the following question on a study guide and was wondering if I did it correctly. I was confused because of the way the question is worded. Here is the question:
[image]

And here is how I attempted it:

[image]

Is this correct?? I was confused because I think the problem asked for confidence interval when it actually meant margin of error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Everything is Ok, except I would use a two tailed critical value of 2.33 ( instead of 2.05)  Further it is not $\alpha=z_{0.49}$ but it is $\frac{\alpha}{2} = {0.01}$ $\alpha = {0.02}$

The procedure is absolutely correct